# What is the best practice in adding logic into Mongoose's Model ctor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hook

Assume simple schema:

```
var NestedSchema = mongooseSchema({
  'id' : Number,
  'someData' : String
});

var MySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  'exampleField' : [NestedSchema]
};
```

I want to create model instance without providing id for each `NestedSchema`, like this:

```
new MySchemaModel({'exampleField' : [{'someData' : 'initial Data'}]});
```

I know there is `pre-save` hook which allows me to set `id` field before saving, but it is not enough for me, because I have to manipulate those data (and use ids) before I save model instance in mongo. So the question is : are there good solutions for including some `pre-create` function to initialize data which be invoked right after `new`? I am looking something similar to `PostConstruct` methods in java managed beans.

Answer (score 2):

Question originally answered [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/672#issuecomment-129006915) by [Valeri Karpov](https://github.com/vkarpov15) - many thanks!

> Take a look at the schema.queue function in the api docs, that enables you to queue up functions to execute every time a new document is created. Mongoose uses it internally for hooks but 4.1.0 formally added that to the public facing API

To just rephrase it, Mongoose 4.1.0 officially supports `schema.queue` which allows hook methods (declared in particular schema) to init chain, so the sollution is quite simple here:

```
MySchema.methods.generateIds = function () {
  // app logic here
}

// ...and at last
MySchema.queue('generateIds');
```

It will trigger `generateIds` method during ctor invoke! Quite simple and fun.

Answer (score 0):

You have some odd naming conventions ( I was taught with camelCase, though originally from PascalCase ) and an odd way of asking. But I think you are asking *"Where is the _id when I create?"*, to which the answer is, it's already there:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var nestedSchema = new Schema({
  id: Number,
  someData: String
},{ "_id": false });

var mySchema = new Schema({
  exampleField: [nestedSchema]
});

var MyModel = mongoose.model( 'MyModel', mySchema, 'mymodel' );


var model = new MyModel();

console.log(model);
```

Which produces something like:

```
{ _id: 55c61af0696bc49a29e4133e, exampleField: [] }
```

So the `_id` is always present when you create new instance, even before you save or do anything else.

Otherwise if you are looking to define an "id" value for your embedded array items and and specifically "ignoring the default `_id` which would be generated as I have then do something like:

```
var nestedSchema = new Schema({
  id: { type: Number, default: genId() },
  someData: String
},{ "_id": false });
```

Where the `genId()` function there returns something for that field value unless specified. So "ideally" the `genId()` function here does something like as docmented in [Create an autoincrementing sequence field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) with a "syncronous" response to assign a brand new "id" value each time the new instance is invoked.

Or otherwise just drop that field and accept the default `_id` value generated by mongoose in arrays like this:

```
var nestedSchema = new Schema({
  id: { type: Number, default: genId() },
  someData: String
});
```

Where `genId()` is an external function to the schema and bascially just retuns a value to be used as a "default" upon creation, where no other value was specified. This also happens "before save" or any other action and is as simple as the instance creation of the object.

And following the example before:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var nestedSchema = new Schema({
  someData: String
});

var mySchema = new Schema({
  exampleField: [nestedSchema]
});

var MyModel = mongoose.model( 'MyModel', mySchema, 'mymodel' );


var model = new MyModel({ "exampleField": [{ "someData": "here" }]});

console.log(model);
```

Which produces:

```
{ _id: 55c633199f529d0b2a890dba,
  exampleField: [ { someData: 'here', _id: 55c633199f529d0b2a890dbb } ] }
```

Comment: This naming convention is borrowed from mongoose docs, so it's maybe odd. My question is not about `_id` field, because of I need different way of numbering than implemented already in mongo (but I mentioned that, didn't I?). Anyway - that is not an answer.

Comment: @DawidPura So what is the question? Mentioned What? I see nothing. No need to act offended because I was not offending.

Comment: I edited question to being more precisely, thanks :)

Comment: @DawidPura Treading carefully here because english is clearly not your native language. But this is not clear at all. What "id" do you want to set? Is it the inner `nestedSchema` ( my example ) entry? And where should the value be coming from? Also note the specific `{ "_id": false }` in my configuration here.

Comment: Yes, I want to set `id` field of `NestedSchema`. Value of `id` will come from external function (will be set by some external application rule). It has nothing to do with `_id` field, so there is no necessity to remove it from schema.

Comment: @DawidPura So I actually just added two alterate approaches while you were typing that. Read them

Comment: `genId` function will be invoked once, thus if I will create more than one object, my ids will be the same. I want to dynamically call something like `genId` function, read object, calculate it and give the right `id` value.

Comment: @DawidPura You really could not be more vague here. I am just stating `genId()` as a "hypothetical" function that returns a "unqiue" id value each time it is invoked. This is a very simple concept. Are you actually asking in your question how to write such a function because you do not know how? Or honestly at this point I am right out of possibilities for what it is that you are even asking here at all. I have been patient, but that is running very short right now.

Comment: Not at all, I am just pointing out that `genId` will be invoked only during schema declaration and won't be invoked for each instance of model.

Comment: @DawidPura You are **wrong**. The function is invoked **per instance**. That is what "default" values do. Stop assuming and actually try something.

Comment: Okay, so if you want to pass a function instead of result you should write `id: { type: Number, default: genId }` instead of `id: { type: Number, default: genId() }`, or JavaScript is working odd here :) Or `getId` returns another function, which means I might be wrong.

Comment: @DawidPura This is really quite simple. On first invoke the `genId()` returns `1` and then on a second invoke it increments again and returns `2`. Do you really need a sample to understand that? You implement a singleton or better yet something along these lines: [Create an auto-incrementing sequence field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/). I do not see why I need to write code in an example that has been written over and over before.